# GPO "Administratively assigned offline files" is applied but files are not available offline

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, samba, windows-10

I've configured a GPO that uses the "Administratively assigned offline files" to make a path `\\server\share\%username%` available offline. It works perfectly fine on my old Windows XP laptop, but my Windows 10 laptop does not sync any files while claiming to have applied the GPO. I also can't find any errors related to GPOs or Offline Files in the Event Log.

The feature "Offline Files" is also enabled via GPO and is present on the Windows 10 machine. It is shown as active in the Sync Center as well. However, I can't make folders/files available offline because the corresponding context menu entry isn't there.

I'm thinking that the feature may not be "completely" enabled for some reason. Are there any individual components I can check?

Comment: In the Sync Center control panel, is Offline Files enabled or disabled?

Comment: @GregAskew it's shown as enabled, I've now added that info to the question.